# How do you update file paths in Xcode 6

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, filepath

I have a file named main.cpp. I want to put it in a folder called myfolder in the project navigator. I drag and drop main.cpp into myfolder. But when I look at the file path for main.cpp it refuses to change, i.e., it is outside the myfolder.

In other words, when I drag and drop my c++ files (or even text files) it doesn't change the path to the file that you moved.

How do you fix this? Intuitively, it would seem that dragging and dropping a file into another folder would change its location, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about XCode groups.

Groups in XCode *are not* folders in your project's folder. If you want XCode and your project's folder to have the same "structure", then you have to remove the files from XCode, then in your project's folder move the files to where you want them to be, and drag the folder back to XCode to import it as a group.

Comment: what purpose does dragging and dropping do in project navigator?